# Are JS setTimeout/setInterval return values reused?

Tags: javascript, timer, cross-browser

I'm aware that return values from `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are unique within a given DOM at least for timers running at that moment, but once one of these timers finishes or is cancelled is the same number ever reused? What about for example `setTimeout` outputting a number which `setInterval` has already given, or similar?

My instinct is that I can rely on them never being reused. Otherwise I'd feel the need to clear variables pointing to a timer identifier as soon as the timer ends or I cancel it, lest some other code attempt to cancel it later when it is pointing to an unrelated timer (which has by chance been assigned the same identifier).

Assuming they are not supposed to be reused, are there any browsers which misbehave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through a chain of specifications and calls, eventually the return value of `setTimeout` / `setInterval` *should* come from "[*the list of active timers*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#list-of-active-timers)":

> Each object that implements the WindowTimers interface has a list of active timers. Each entry in this lists is identified by a number, which must be unique within the list for the lifetime of the object that implements the WindowTimers interface.

As the section specifies, the number is unique for the lifetime of the (*object that...*) `window` object, which is maintained for the lifetime of to page.

However, regarding implementation and "misbehaving browsers", I don't think that's really answerable.

Comment: Can you clarify your "As the section specifies" line? It's not totally clear to me from the quoted part of the specification or your conclusion what the "object" is: are you clarifying that it's the page, or could it be some part of the page?

Comment: Why isn't it answerable? Source code is available for some browsers, and somebody who has studied it may know whether for example old versions of Firefox or Chromium do this wrong. Or somebody may know from experimentation that particular versions of closed source browsers do things wrong.

Comment: see the edited answer. the `window` object is the one that implements the interface (and hence you use `window.setTimeout`). As for the the other browsers, it *might* be that someone knows a broken implementation, but even if no one does it doesn't meen there isn't any.